# Laravel 5.5: The page has expired due to inactivity

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, csrf-protection

I am experiencing a problem with Laravel 5.5 csrf tokens expiring prematurely. My session timeout is set to 240 minutes, however, the csrf tokens appear to expire if a form is 'left open' in the browser (ie, not posted to) within 10 minutes.

To be clear, my problem has (categorically) nothing to do with correct inclusion of the {{ csrf_field() }} tag. I'm including the tag and, for the most part, it works perfectly except that the lifespan of the csrf tokens is exceedingly short.

I found few suggested solutions that involve changing the stock framework middleware but want to avoid hacks. I'm hoping that someone might know how I can make the csrf timeout consistent with session timeout.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, it seems a cached env value (and my own stupidity) was the culprit. For reference, I had set SESSION_LIFETIME to "10" in order to test expiry and somehow pushed the same value into my production .env file.